# Convert a table to graph or time series on Grafana

Tags: grafana

This table is created using a mixed data source (Cloudwatch + Mysql) on Grafana.

| Field | Datatype |
| --- | --- |
| Time | Timestamp |
| Metric | String |
| Value | Integer |

Now I'm unable to convert this table to a graph.

If graph option is selected from Visualization tab, X-axis is `Time`, Y-axis is `value` and no legend is present.

Can someone please help. Thanks in advance.

[image: Table]

[image: Graph]

Comment: You have wrong time series - one date has 2 different values + I guess data are not in the time order.

Comment: @JanGaraj Yes. One time has two different values. But the mount_point (column name) for that two rows is different.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Transform > Prepare time series > Multi-frame time series`.

In my example table, I only have a single date, but it should work with more. This is my table before: 1 date, 4 labels with their values
[image: Table before]
When I use the transform, the table becomes 2D and my label column is recognized as such
[image: Table after with label selector]
Yayy we can plot time series now!
[image: Yayy we have a time series now!]

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to try. Rename the mount_point column to "metric" and  rename readops to value.  This will hopefully help Grafana interpret the data. Are you sure the mount_point is a string data type, if not convert that to a string